# The Bokeh SaveTool is not saving images properly in 2.1.1

Tags: bokeh

I've been using Bokeh for years and just updated to 2.1.1, and I can't get the SaveTool in the toolbar next to plots to work properly anymore. Instead of downloading the entire image, it downloads the upper left corner and omits everything else. The ubiquity of the phenomenon is a little overwhelming. It happens in all browsers, in all the Jupyter notebooks I use, in all HTML outputs. However, if I revert to an earlier version everything is fine.

As for code, I can even generate the problem at docs.bokeh.org in a single Chrome browser:

Here I get the entirety of the first plot on the page:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/1.0.0/docs/gallery/image.html

Here I just get the upper left corner of the first plot on the page:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/image.html

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. The fix is already in the release branch and will be part of the next release.